# Will my app be rejected if the icon has rounded corners?

Tags: ios

The [guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) specify that I *"should provide an image that has 90° corners (it’s important to avoid cropping the corners of your icon—iOS does that for you when it applies the corner-rounding mask)"*

I see lots of apps that disobey this recommendation. **How big is the risk that Apple will reject my app based on the app icon's rounded corners?**

[image: app icon with rounded corners]

Comment: Why are my iPhone app related questions being close-voted so much today? As long as there's no better place for [App Store related questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores), my question ison topic!

Comment: I don't mind downvotes and close votes -- but I kindly request a comment to state the reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this before and haven't been rejected for it. Just make sure that your icons corners align properly with the corners applied by iOS. (could look pretty strange if they didn't) As long as the fact that you're manually setting the corners isn't obvious to the user you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! I've checked the app icon on the deployed beta version, and it looks fine. So at least _that_ shouldn't be a reason for rejection.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I wouldn't worry about it, your icon looks good and I can't see them giving you any trouble over this, But regardless of what I think you may be lucky enough to get Apples pickiest reviewer. Good luck though!

Comment: yeah that would be typical for my luck. The wikipedia entry for "unlucky person" should contain nothing but my name, repeated infinitely ;-)